# codeigniter application view folder location issue in fresh application

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

`Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php` i'm getting this error, i don't know what is wrong, i downloaded the rc3(release candidate 3) from the official website, unzipped it, added asset folder and helper and when i ran the application, i got the error `Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php`, this is my `index.php` file code and image shows the folder structure

```
// index.php code
<?php
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP
 *
 * This content is released under the MIT License (MIT)
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2014 - 2015, British Columbia Institute of Technology
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 * @package CodeIgniter
 * @author  EllisLab Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2014, EllisLab, Inc. (http://ellislab.com/)
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 - 2015, British Columbia Institute of Technology (http://bcit.ca/)
 * @license http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT  MIT License
 * @link    http://codeigniter.com
 * @since   Version 1.0.0
 * @filesource
 */

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * You can load different configurations depending on your
 * current environment. Setting the environment also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 */
    define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER\['CI_ENV'\]) ? $_SERVER\['CI_ENV'\] : 'development');

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    break;

    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>='))
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        }
        else
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
        }
    break;

    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
        exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" folder.
 * Include the path if the folder is not in the same directory
 * as this file.
 */
    $system_path = 'system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * folder than the default one you can set its name here. The folder
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server. If
 * you do, use a full server path. For more info please see the user guide:
 * http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 */
    $application_folder = 'application';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * VIEW FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want to move the view folder out of the application
 * folder set the path to the folder here. The folder can be renamed
 * and relocated anywhere on your server. If blank, it will default
 * to the standard location inside your application folder. If you
 * do move this, use the full server path to this folder.
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 */
    $view_folder = '';


/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * DEFAULT CONTROLLER
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file.
 * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a
 * specific controller class/function here. For most applications, you
 * WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those
 * special instances where you might want to override the standard
 * routing in a specific front controller that shares a common CI installation.
 *
 * IMPORTANT: If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be
 * callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE
 * specific controller. Leave the function name blank if you need
 * to call functions dynamically via the URI.
 *
 * Un-comment the $routing array below to use this feature
 */
    // The directory name, relative to the "controllers" folder.  Leave blank
    // if your controller is not in a sub-folder within the "controllers" folder
    // $routing\['directory'\] = '';

    // The controller class file name.  Example:  mycontroller
    // $routing\['controller'\] = '';

    // The controller function you wish to be called.
    // $routing\['function'\]   = '';


/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the
 * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config
 * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file.
 * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application between
 * multiple front controller files, with each file containing different
 * config values.
 *
 * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array below to use this feature
 */
    // $assign_to_config\['name_of_config_item'\] = 'value of config item';



// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS.  DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Resolve the system path for increased reliability
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

    // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
    if (defined('STDIN'))
    {
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    }

    if (($_temp = realpath($system_path)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_path = $_temp.'/';
    }
    else
    {
        // Ensure there's a trailing slash
        $system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';
    }

    // Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Now that we know the path, set the main path constants
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    // The name of THIS file
    define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

    // Path to the system folder
    define('BASEPATH', str_replace('\\', '/', $system_path));

    // Path to the front controller (this file)
    define('FCPATH', dirname(__FILE__).'/');

    // Name of the "system folder"
    define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));

    // The path to the "application" folder
    if (is_dir($application_folder))
    {
        if (($_temp = realpath($application_folder)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $application_folder = $_temp;
        }

        define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
            echo 'Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
            exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
        }

        define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    }

    // The path to the "views" folder
    if ( ! is_dir($view_folder))
    {
        if ( ! empty($view_folder) && is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
        {
            $view_folder = APPPATH.$view_folder;
        }
        elseif ( ! is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
            echo 'Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
            exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
        }
        else
        {
            $view_folder = APPPATH.'views';
        }
    }

    if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $view_folder = $_temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    else
    {
        $view_folder = rtrim($view_folder, '/\\').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder);

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

[image]

Comment: you can debug why its going in `elseif ( ! is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))`. what is in your htaccess?

Comment: it has correct path appfolder/application/views :\

Comment: Is appfolder the root of you application?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem on Linux. The path was correct but the user (apache) didn't have permission to access the folder, so the 'is_dir' function returned FALSE.

I just changed the user and group permissions following this guide and now works OK: http://fideloper.com/user-group-permissions-chmod-apache

Hope it do the trick.

Comment: Changing the entire Apache's DocumentRoot (/var/www in my case) permissions, including all its subfolders and files. It makes the apache user can access all my CodeIgniter content.

Comment: For me it was the same issue, however the steps in the given link changed all /var/html owner to www-data, not allowing me to edit files :) So I had to change permissions of read-write for my user (for development stage)

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the root index. In CI you must set your controller to load a page within folder "view".

something like 
Controller file: /controller/admin.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Admin extends CI_Controller {     
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();      
    }
    public function index(){        
        $this->load->view('home');  
    }
}
```

Then your view file: /view/home.php:

```
<html>
Hello world
</html>
```

I suggest you use the stable version. Last January released is v 2.2.1.
I'm using 2.2.0.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very common reason you have to just update short code to long code for php declation in index.php file OR you can also enable short code allow in php.ini file.

```
<?
```

Replace with

```
<?php
```

Cheers!

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I have also face this kind of problem...
It is only because of a permission issue..

Just open the terminal and type this command:

```
chmod -R 777 "name of your project folder"
```

It works for me.